# Download image files using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to download image files from the following webpages:

```
urls = 
['https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/VLu8pOKuwWz6rgeEDzAW1w/o.jpg'
'https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/-s4vJyj65E5q88MjpnIMSA/o.jpg'
'https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/cVk72YkYxrF17myMHAp1dQ/o.jpg']
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib

for i in urls:
     urllib.urlretrieve(i, ???.jpg)
```

One image file from each url, so I would like to save the files as following:

```
VLu8pOKuwWz6rgeEDzAW1w.jpg
-s4vJyj65E5q88MjpnIMSA.jpg
cVk72YkYxrF17myMHAp1dQ.jpg
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired filename is in url itself,so make use of it by `split()`

```
urls =['https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/VLu8pOKuwWz6rgeEDzAW1w/o.jpg','https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/-s4vJyj65E5q88MjpnIMSA/o.jpg','https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/cVk72YkYxrF17myMHAp1dQ/o.jpg']
import urllib
for i in urls:
    j=i.split('/')[-2] # Splitting by '/' and assigning it to the name
    urllib.urlretrieve(i,'{}.jpg'.format(j))
```

[Check this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)